# Shipping Rate based on Cart Total v.1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, ups, usps

We need to figure out a way to only provide **real time** UPS rates if cart totals are over $65. This could be if a single product is over $65 or if multiple low priced items total over $65 - meaning we can't simply apply shipping rules to all products priced over $65. A user could buy a bunch of t-shirts that total over $65 and we would need UPS to be the only rate that appears.

Otherwise, if cart totals are less than $65, **real time** USPS rate will also be offered (in addition to UPS).

Is this possible? If so, how would we accomplish this?

Comment: I resolved this myself by finding a module:

https://amasty.com/shipping-restrictions.html